# Solution explorer not showing files, not because the show/all files button

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, solution-explorer

I have a solution checked into TFS. Looking in the source control explorer I have a .cs file in the solution. But looking in the solution explorer it's missing.

When the project is built it takes the file into consideration and it's code is included in the build.

A collegue of mine has successfully pulled the code from TFS and built it and everything appears as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I know you have stated that this isn't due to the show all files button, but what happens when you click it? Does the file still not appear? If so, please give some information about the structure of your working folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a full reinstall fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  What I did was, keeping the solution/projects open. Went to windows explorer, deleted all the files of that project which was not showing the files. Then from TFS, got all the files for that project. Then was prompted to reload the project, and voila - the files showed up. Not sure why this happened though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the .cs file is missing from disk, or you have a stale copy of the .csproj file, or something along those lines.  Use the Folder Diff tool to see what's going on.  'tf folderdiff', or rightclick -> Compare on a folder in Source Control Explorer.

Comment: I'll give that a try and get back to you.

Comment: Tried comparing the files and it's all ok, deleted solution from machine and then got the latest version from TFS and same issue. Pulled on another machine and everything is correct so pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the source control repository. One thing to mention is that the project in question is a test project.